# i try to add value array in array using push(),but i dont know how to add it

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

this mycode, I try to value in company1 staff, but it create a new list of array. can someone help me?

after I add the name and id of staff the array  will look like this

> [{companyName: "company1",companyAddress: "company address",staff:
>   [{name:"men",id: "123"},{name:"boy",id: "1343"},{name:"john",id:
>   "145"}]}]

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="nameStaff" />
    <input type="text" ng-model="idStaff" />
    <button ng-click=addDetail()>add</button>
    {{form}}
</div>

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.form = [{ companyName: "company1", companyAddress: "company address", staff: [{ name: "men", id: "123" }] }];
    $scope.addDetail = function() {
        $scope.form.push({ staff: [{ name: $scope.nameStaff, id: $scope.idStaff }] });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pushing on to the `form`, but you want to push on to the `staff` of the first object in the `form`:

```
$scope.form[0].staff.push({
  name: $scope.nameStaff,
  id: $scope.idStaff
});
```

Comment: closing bracket is missing in above $scope.form[0].staff.push({
  name: $scope.nameStaff,
  id: $scope.idStaff
});